# Review > Recommend Deletion - Grammar

Tags: bug, low-quality-posts

Under "Review > Low Quality Posts > Recommend Deletion", the option:

> This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment

Should not really have a comma after the word ***problem*** before the word ***too***

> This is an “I’m having this problem too” comment

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If this was really the most important thing to fix on the site I'd be one happy camper!

Comment: The way I learned it in school, the comma should be there. But then, that was a *long* time ago, so maybe the rules have changed...

Comment: For some reason when I saw the title of this question in the hot meta posts list, my initial reaction was to say "Delete the words.  **All** the words!"

Answer (score 5):

But

> I’m having this problem too

means something like

> I'm having another problem and this one also

while

> I’m having this problem, too

means something like

> I too am having this problem

And, yes, I'm posting this entirely mischievously with the intention of provoking the thought that delicate questions of the 'correctness' of punctuating English are, at bottom, matters of opinion.

The question may also be off-topic here, and might perhaps be better asked on https://english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Comma rules are complicated, especially, when English is not primary language :|

Comment: They're even more complicated when one is a native speaker of English and stray beyond the prescriptions of pedagogical sources.  Out here in the trenches, grammer bloodbath a is, not mention speling.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/8111

Comment: grammer.... *shudders*